# CSS Transitions

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-transitions

I have created the jQuery Script below, But am having a few problems converting it to preferably only CSS using transitions. If anybody could help me, I'll be greatfull.

**Explanation of the example below:**
 - When you click on the text box a empty div container drops down, but I am having a few problems with scripting it in just mainly CSS3 Transitions.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="textbox"/>
    <p>example</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.textbox {width:300px;}
.div { width:300px; background-color:#f8f8f8; }
p {width:300px; height:300px; background-color: #f8f8f8;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#textbox").click(function() {
    $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE/28/)**

Comment: When I click on the text box, the `<p>` tags slides up...there's no empty `<div>` that drops down.  Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Oh sorry, Yes there is a <p> inside the div, But I'm looking for it in mainly CSS Transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .3s;
}
input:focus + p {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE/33/ (click to focus on the `input`).

---

**P.S.** Don't forget the vendor prefixes. The fiddle uses [`-prefix-free`](https://raw.github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/gh-pages/prefixfree.min.js) to auto-add the vendor prefixes.

Comment: That is the part I am having trouble with, but thank you anyway

Comment: @user1608656 - Can you explain what trouble you're having? Does the fiddle work the way you intend it to? If not, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I am having trouble the vendor prefixes, and have tried scripting it, But have failed. - The result would be clicking on a text box and a div drops down, In CSS3 Transitions. - Just like the jQuery Demo, But in CSS3.

Comment: @user1608656 - This is exactly what happens in the fiddle I've linked to. It's all done in CSS3 - no JavaScript.

Comment: About the prefixes - Do I have to add that in my code if I save it as a .HTML file?

Comment: @user1608656 - Yes. If you want to target non-bleeding-edge browsers, you'll need those prefixes in production. You can use a tool such as [`prefixr`](http://prefixr.com/) to help you out with this.